# SII - Suministro Inmediato de informacion - haciendas forales

Tags: c#, aeat-sii

Ya he realizado el desarrollo para enviar a hacienda el SII pero ahora se nos plantea el envío a las haciendas forales de Navarra y País Vasco. Con la de Navarra no tuvimos problemas pero con la de País Vasco nos da error al Parsear el XML.

Tras comparar los ficheros que se envían nos dimos cuenta que la diferencia está en el namespace que para hacienda española es:

```
<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
```

y para alava es

```
<SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns="https://sii.araba.eus/documentos/SuministroLR.xsd">.
```

Mi pregunta es cómo podemos modificar solo el namespace a la hora de hacer la llamada al método :

```
SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas objEnvioFacturas = null;
RespuestaLRFRecibidasType objRespuestaFacturas = null;
objSWFact.Timeout = Configuracion.Configuracion.SIITimeOutEnvio * 1000;

objEnvioFacturas = new SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas()
            {
                Cabecera = (CabeceraSii)ObtenerCabecera(cliente, argstrTipoComunicacion),
                RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas = ObtenerFacturasRecibidas(_mdecIdEmpresas, cliente, argstrTipoComunicacion, argstrFechaDesde, argstrFechaHasta, ref strMensajeFacturasErroreas, ref facturasEnviadas, argdecIdCaimtransacciones, argblnPrimerSemestre)
            };
            objRespuestaFacturas = objSWFact.SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas((SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas)objEnvioFacturas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución depende de cómo se coloca el namespace en el XML en primer lugar.

Sabiendo la respuesta a eso quizás puedas hacer algo previamente antes de generar el XML para que se genere con un namespace o con otro.

Creo que falta mostrar más código de tu aplicación para entender debidamente por dónde se podría solucionar el problema.

Si la cadena XML la generas manualmente desde tu programación ahí tienes la respuesta, modifica el valor que pasas en ese atributo.

Pero me parece que en tu caso la codificación de objeto c# a XML la está realizando algún tipo de cliente SOAP que instanciaste por lo tanto lo que yo entiendo es que el cliente SOAP al leer la definición desde la WSDL País Vasco debería saber cómo codificar correctamente el dato antes de enviarlo.

Ahora bien lo único que se me puede ocurrir, ya que como digo es muy poco código/info para saber con certeza, es que quizás hayas generado localmente unos objetos en base a la definición de la Agencia Tributaria de España y esos objetos los estás instanciando para llenarlos con los datos antes de pasarlos como parámetro al comando del cliente de webservice. Dicho esto, quizás tengas que generar otra version de esos objetos a partir de la definición de SII de País Vasco.

También te cuento cómo trabajo en mi caso con PHP y SoapClient:

1. No genero ningunas clases locales a partir de ninguna definición
2. Simplemente creo un array asociativo multi-nivel de PHP, con toda la estructura, cabecera y filas
3. Luego simplemente llamo a `$cliente->metodo($datos)` y el mismo SoapClient de PHP codifica mi array asociativo al XML que necesita antes de enviarlo

Por lo tanto entiendo que en mi caso si en vez de conectarme a la WSDL de la Agencia Tributaria principal de España, me conectara a la URL de la de País Vasco, debería funcionar de forma automática.

Espero que te sirva de algo y si aportas más datos estaré encantado de darte un feedback aunque no tengo experiencia con c# sino con php.

Por último, comentarte que en http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ he redactado un ebook que contiene una guía técnica para realizar una implementación básica del SII, explica temas generales de los servicios web, uso de certificados, y contiene ejemplos de código en PHP junto con una mini aplicación que une todas las partes del circuito de comunicación con el SII.